# Не отображается стиль элемента в Firebug

Tags: html, css

Есть сайт http://topol5.tmweb.ru/

У меня там есть стиль

```
.content2 .body .catalog .pos .img .hov li.25 
{ 
    background:url (images/jacusi.png) no-repeat 0 center;
}
```

В  firebug он почему-то не хочет отображаться применительно к элементу .25

Нужно отдельно иконку поставить туда, при наведении на блок с септиками

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Имя css класса не может начинаться с цифры, поэтому селектор и не отрабатывает.
Существующие в этом коде классы 'l5' 'l4' и тд начинаются со строчной буквы 'l' а не с цифры. Назовите класс по-другому, переправьте соответственно селектор и все будет пучком